# Advanced graph SQL question

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph

I have a directed graph described by `A -> B` meaning that there exists a connection, always weight 1, FROM A TO B.  The problem I want to solve (This is not an academic project) is how can I tell how many common connections there are between two nodes.

To say that in terms of A and B.
There are 2 things that need to get done,
* To look at all of my, B, links coming in (All A's to some B)
* Count how many common A's out of all My, Original B, A's.

I do not know if that makes sense but I'll show you how far I have come.
*  First point.

```
SELECT A
FROM graph
WHERE B='myid';
```

As most can tell, part 1 is a very simple question.  Part 2 is where things get tricky.
I have been able to get all the A's with at least 1 connection or more similar.

Second point.

```
SELECT G.A, count( G2.A ) AS common
FROM graph AS G2
JOIN (
    SELECT A, B
    FROM graph
    WHERE B = 'myid'
) AS G ON G.A = G2.B
```

So the second point is close because it will return all common links, **but** it will not return all links which have no common links.  Is there a way to get that too?

---

There is still confusion:  Ill try to draw a picture... with words.
Here is the table.

```
A, B
-----   
2, 1  
3, 1  
2, 3
```

If I wanted to see how many common links from all incoming links into NODE 1 I **should** see

```
A, count
---------  
2, 1 // This is for 2's connection to 3.  
3, 0
```

With the current SQL statement I have I see this.

```
A, count
---------  
2, 1 // This is for 2's connection to 3.
```

Comment: Oh, One more thing.  The table looks like this [a, b]  Thats it.  Meaning A has a directed link to B (A => B)

Comment: what do you want to count ? how many connection to B from the same A ? .... What do you mean by "common" ?

Comment: Like facebook where you can see how many friends you have in common with one of your friends.  I want to see how many common links ALL of my directed links into some B (All of B's A's).  Right now it will only return the A's with common links between other A's within B, but i want the ones also that have no common links.

Comment: I made an edit to help visualize whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a subquery, I would just use JOINs:

```
SELECT
    N1.A,
    COUNT(N3.A)
FROM
    Nodes N1
INNER JOIN Nodes N2 ON
    N2.B = 'myid'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodes N3 ON
    N3.A = N1.A AND
    N3.B = N2.A
WHERE
    N1.B = 'myid'
GROUP BY
    N1.A
```

This gives the answer that you are expecting in your example. You may want to test it out on a wider sample.

You should also do performance testing on this if your data set is of any significant size.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this?  I really like the statement and you did a great job!

Comment: This was the first thing that popped into my head. If I think of a better way then I'll post it.

Comment: Yeah, there will be thousands, if not millions soon for data.  So i will need to optimize this!  that is why i was trying to do it with 1 statement and no group by's.

Comment: Well, assuming that you have an index on B, the cross join shouldn't be too bad (unless a single end-point has many rows - tens of thousands?). The index on B will immediately cut down your working resultsets for table aliases N1 and N2. I'd try mocking up some data that mimics patterns that you expect to see and then test against that for performance.

Comment: Ok i figured out a faster way of doing things... I think.  `SELECT F.A, COUNT(F2.A)
FROM fans AS F
LEFT OUTER JOIN fans AS F2 
ON F.A = F2.B
WHERE F.B = 'aca004b430a71f6dc0789c2da78d22b1'
GROUP BY F.A`

Comment: Its almost identical to yours except for i removed the inner join statement.  Currently the index is a compound one in the order of B, A.  I think i might remove it soon and make it just index B, index A

Comment: The results of your query look wrong to me. You may want to doule-check it. For indexing, it of course depends on your data and how you will typically be querying it, but in similar situations I would usually use a compound clustered index on (A, B) or (B, A) and then a nonclustered index on the second column of the clustered index. So, (A, B) and (B) or (B, A) and (A). Which I would use again depends on how the table will mostly be used.